# How to extract data from a table via curl?

Tags: php, xml, curl

How to extract table data `<table bgcolor="#004e8e" width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" id="borda_bai">` site http://www.orientcinemas.com.br/programacao/cinema.php?cod=5 with php?

And another question is how to put each data table in a xml?

Ex: a table of the same site

> C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 
>   
> L1
>  L2
>  L4
>  L5

And in xml
C1L1 =>
 
`<C1>`
                 `<L1> </ L1>`
                 `<L2> </ L2>`
                
`</ C1>`

Facilitate the handling / use of data: (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [XPathSelector](https://github.com/stil/xpath-selector):

```
$xs = XPathSelector\Document::loadHTMLFile('http://www.orientcinemas.com.br/programacao/cinema.php?cod=5');
$table = $xs->select('//*[@id="borda_bai"][1]');
$result = array();
$row = 0;
foreach ($table->select('tr[position()>1]') as $tr) {
    $row++;
    $column = 0;
    foreach ($tr->select('td') as $td) {
        $column++;
        $result[$row][$column] = $td->extract();
    }
}
```

And the $result will be

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 243
            [3] => A Saga Crep├║sculo: Amanhecer - Parte 2
            [4] => 12a.
            [5] => Dub. - 13h30, 16h00, 18h30, 21h00
        )
    etc......
)
```

Comment: It seems pretty simple but I do not know installing it or where I'm developing in xampp or the server. I know very little PHP: (

Comment: Learn [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/), then you will be able to install XPathSelector without the problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Matthias Kerstner's HTML Table Extractor.

> http://www.kerstner.at/en/2011/02/html-table-extractor/

Answer (score 0):

Curl doesn't do that. Curl is used to make requests. Parsing html you describe can be done with DOM, XPath and SimpleXML.